# Irrelevant answers and expiring bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

What should one do about answers which are true and might be helpful for some but do not address the question that is asked? I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706851/2855190)

The answer, in essence, is a good advice, even if it isn't necessarily true, but it does not answer the question nor does it help in getting closer to solving the problem.

Regardless of what I think, the bounty is expiring in a few days and I have no suitable answers to reward it to but by default it will go to that answer which (to me) does not seem entirely fair, or do community wiki's don't get bounties?. Then again since it's gotten 2 up-votes it must be helpful for some.

I'm just curious as to what others would do.

Comment: Not sure whether that answer *can* receive the bounty, given that Hans made it community wiki (quite certainly to signal that he doesn't want the bounty).

Comment: Oke so that's what that was about, i found it odd it went to community wiki almost right after posting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [bounty will get awarded to the CW](https://meta.superuser.com/a/267/144040) as Jeff Atwood wrote:

> The bounty does not care whether the question is CW or not and will be awarded if it meets the rules.